# Finding the PMF of $X^2$ given the PMF of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The random variable $X$ has the probability mass function $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 x e^{-x^2} & \text{if } x \ge 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ Find the PMF of $X^{2}$.

---

**My attempt**. Put $Y=X^{2}$, then we have

$$ F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y)=P(X^{2} \leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y})$$

Since we have that $x\ge0$ we can discard the lower bound. So we have

$$ P (0 \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = \int_0^\sqrt{y} f(x) dx = \int_0^\sqrt{y} 2xe^{-x^2} dx = 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-y} = F_Y(y) $$

Taking the derivative of the CDF for $Y$ we get $y e^{-y}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Remark: when your random variable is continuous, it is called the PDF - probability density function.

Comment: Minor point: your argument only works for $y \ge 0$.  What about for $y < 0$?

Comment: @geetha290krm what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything correct except for the last step. The derivative of $$1 - e^{-y}$$ is $$e^{-y}$$

So the correct answer is $$X^2\text~Exponential(1)$$

Comment: What a blunder. Luckily I did not make this mistake during the exam.